# Why did my server repeatedly request the packages.bz2 file from a mirror for 24 hours?

Tags: server, apt, 10.04

One of our servers ended up using about 20 GB of data yesterday because it was repeatedly requesting the packages.bz2 file from a mirror.

The requests began about 22:00 on Sunday night, and stopped about 21:00 on the Monday.

There is nothing in the apt history, unattended-upgrades, or the system log to indicate why.

All I can see is a bunch of blocked traffic in the UFW log from the mirror IP address - there are no rules to block this IP in the UFW setup, communication to the mirror is successful outside this period of unusual activity, so it looks like flood protection (though I've gone through the UFW configuration and couldn't find this explicitly set).

`/var/log/apt/term.log` and `/var/log/apt/term.log` have no entries after 6:45 last Friday (2 whole days before the event started).

`/var/log/aptitude` is empty since its creation over a year ago.

`auth.log` shows normal cron activity for an Ubuntu server - and not a lot else besides my logins and use of `sudo` when trying to diagnose the problems on there.

There is nothing in cron.d calling apt or aptitude - and cron.daily has the same collection of scripts as other servers that are not misbehaving.

I've spoken with the sysadmin for the mirror - he was very helpful. This is how I found out that my server was requesting the packages.bz2 file repeatedly. He says that each request was fulfilled and closed correctly.

So - what could have happened to start this process? Why would it go on for so long, and why did it just stop?

---

And one week later, it started again - still nothing in the logs to indicate why.

Comment: Are you using Lucid? What is the contents of `/var/log/apt/term.log` `/var/log/aptitude`

Comment: @Braiam - I've added that information to my questions

Comment: "All I can see is a bunch of blocked traffic in the UFW log from the mirror IP address." <-- What do you actually see? Is that incoming or outgoing traffic (from the firewall's perspective)? And if it's blocked, it should not use any bandwidth.

Comment: While it's happening, make sure to monitor the network usage on your machine. Use tools like `iftop`, `netstat`, `atop`, `tcpdump` to see more about it. As your question currently stands, this is a needle in a haystack. Remember we can't see your screen and we don't have access to your machine, so we rely on the information in your question. I suggest to get familiar with basic troubleshooting with the tools I mentioned. This site isn't really made for trial&error finding the needle in a haystack, I'm afraid.

Comment: the logs doesn't register every call to `apt-get update`. Maybe the `auth.log` and the cron scripts may be more relevant.

Comment: @gertvdijk "basic troubleshooting" was done - all those tools show is that the machine requested the updates file, and received it, and requested it again and again... you're right, it is a needle in a haystack, but the point of sites like this is that someone somewhere has probably had the same experience and can give more guidance than "get familiar with basic troubleshooting".

Comment: @HorusKol This site is for primarily for asking succinct questions, like "How do I do this or that?". As I already pointed out, it isn't really made for trial&error finding the needle in a haystack, I'm afraid. It's not a discussion forum. For getting useful answers, please narrow down your question. E.g. "How do I find out which process on this server queries <URL>?"

Comment: @gertvdijk FAQ would argue against you

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get update` isn't logged in the APT logs.

To me, it appears that the server didn't get the file, or it was invalid. Another possibility is a strange cron script.

Now the reason is a bit more interesting.
Either

1. There is maybe a cron to run `apt-get update`
2. Someone (another admin and/or hacker) was spamming `apt-get update`

Why it would run 23 hours... Maybe a bad cron entry?

Also, not really an expert on UFW/blocking.

Personally, I would check cron, and `auth.log` as @Braiam suggested.

Answer (score 0):

To me this sounds like a scripts loop.

Does the system happen to be set to update it's software at sundays at around 22.00?

Do you have some sort of script running for updating it without attendance?

Comment: I believe this MAY be a dupe answer.... =]